# Find combinations of list in specific order Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, combinations

I have a list such as

```
descr_list = ["I","LOVE","DOGS"]
```

I want a loop that can create sub lists in the order below

```
["I","LOVE","DOGS"]
["I","LOVE"]
["I"]
["LOVE","DOGS"]
["LOVE"]
["DOGS"]
```

Here is the loop i currently have and i am getting the below output

```
for r in range(len(descr_list)):
    for j in range(r+1,len(descr_list)+1):
        result = descr_list[r:j]
        print(result)

['i']
['i', 'love']
['i', 'love', 'dogs']
['love']
['love', 'dogs']
['dogs']
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I know I've done this before but i just can't remember how i did it haha. I need to start at the first element(we can call x) in the list and it needs to read all elements after it. Then walk backwards by 1 element until it gets back to itself and then jump to the next element(x+1) and repeat the same process above until we reach the last element in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested loops:

```
l = len(descr_list)
for i in range(l):
    for j in range(l, i, -1):
        print(f"{descr_list[i:j]} slice from {i} to {j}")

['I', 'LOVE', 'DOGS'] slice from 0 to 3
['I', 'LOVE'] slice from 0 to 2
['I'] slice from 0 to 1
['LOVE', 'DOGS'] slice from 1 to 3
['LOVE'] slice from 1 to 2
['DOGS'] slice from 2 to 3
```

I printed `i` and `j` for a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools` for getting all the combinations of the original `list`:

```
import itertools

descr_list = ["I","LOVE","DOGS"]

combos = []
for i in range(len(descr_list)):
    combos += list(itertools.combinations(descr_list, i+1))
```

So `combos` is:

```
[('I',),
 ('LOVE',),
 ('DOGS',),
 ('I', 'LOVE'),
 ('I', 'DOGS'),
 ('LOVE', 'DOGS'),
 ('I', 'LOVE', 'DOGS')]
```

To get the sort you want, look at the first word of each element of `combos` and find its position (i.e. `index()`) within `descr_list`.  Use that as a `key` for the `sort`, but also the length of the group to prioritize longer combinations first:

```
>>> sorted(combos, key=lambda x: (descr_list.index(x[0]), 1/len(x)))

[('I', 'LOVE', 'DOGS'),
 ('I', 'LOVE'),
 ('I', 'DOGS'),
 ('I',),
 ('LOVE', 'DOGS'),
 ('LOVE',),
 ('DOGS',)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing there's a better way... but I believe this should work:

```
    descr_list = ["I", "LOVE", "DOGS"]
    
    for word_index, word in enumerate(descr_list):
        for i in range(len(descr_list),0,-1):
            if descr_list[word_index:i]:
                result = descr_list[word_index:i]
                print(result)
```

Comment: ... and while I was working on my solution, it appears Pablo C came up with a better solution

Answer (score 0):

```
 mylist = ["I","LOVE","DOGS"]

 sentences=[]
 for b in range(len(mylist)):
      for i in range(len(mylist),b,-1):
           sentence=[]
      for j in range(b,i):
            sentence.append(mylist[j])
      sentences.append(sentence)


  print(sentences)

  output:
  [['I', 'LOVE', 'DOGS'], ['I', 'LOVE'], ['I'], ['LOVE', 'DOGS'], ['LOVE'], ['DOGS']]
```